# Gradle - how can I extract a filter to a separate reusable function?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have defined a copy task in a gradle build script with a filter, but I would like to be able to extract it so that it can be used in multiple places whilst only being defined once.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
def subbingCopy = project.copySpec{
  filter {
    String line ->
      line.replaceAll('\\$\\{project\\.version\\}', "${project.version}").
          replaceAll('\\$\\{project\\.name\\}', "${project.name}")
    }
}

package.doLast {
  copy {
    from ("from/path") {
     include '**/*'
    }
  into ("to/path")
  with subbingCopy
}
```

I've tried various other ways the just fail the build, and this way just doesn't apply the filter.

Is there a way I can do this with the filter being applied to every 'into'?

Comment: It's unclear. Could you please clarify? What do you mean by _every into_?

Comment: So, each time I use 'copy...' followed by 'into...' I would like it to apply the 'filter...' stage from the 'subbingCopy' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example should do the job:

```
ext.someFilter = { String line ->
      line.replaceAll('\\$\\{project\\.version\\}', "${project.version}").
          replaceAll('\\$\\{project\\.name\\}', "${project.name}")
}

package.doLast {
  copy {
    from ("from/path") {
     include '**/*'
    }
  into ("to/path")
  filter(someFilter)
}
```